# Is there a way to track used and remaining execution time quota of the day in G Suite account for Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-for-business

Is there a way to query used and remaining execution time [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of the day in G Suite account for Apps Script?

I am hoping to understand the above and thus be able to tell whether a different G Suite user running my script as a web app using their own log-in will count towards my execution time quota or theirs.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> I am hoping to understand the above and thus be able to tell whether a different G Suite user running my script as a web app using their own log-in will count towards my execution time quota or theirs.

See the [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033976/1595451) to [Is there any limit on number of concurrent hits or simultaneous executions on Google App Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17512194/1595451). Summary: web apps set to "run as me" (script owner) will use the owner's quota.